# Windows 10 sidebar library under the Desktop

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sidebar

Notice how **This PC** is only located under **Desktop**. Collapsing **Desktop** hides everything that should be one indentation to the left.

Is there a fix for this? Right clicking and/or dragging and dropping does not present the solution unfortunately.

EDIT: Solution was found in the comments.

[image: chopped screenshot of the issue not fucking around]

Comment: Try resetting  Windows 10 File Explorer to defaults.  Right click on Quick Access. Click on Options. Go to the View Tab. Click on Reset folders  Click OK. Restart File Explorer and test.

Comment: Legit advise -- it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the File Explorer arrangement, reset Windows 10 File Explorer to defaults.

```
Right click on Quick Access. 
Click on Options. 
Go to the View Tab. 
Click on Reset folders 
Click OK. 
Restart File Explorer and test.
```

This works in a number of cases.

Answer (score 0):

That view is normal when `Show all foldetrs` is selected in Navigation Pane options:
[image]

Turn it off and you have a select view of Desktop items:
[image]